# Hyperlink in UILabel when language can change

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uilabel

I have a requirement to hyperlink some text within a UILabel in Swift.

The solutions I've seen involve pinpointing the character positions in order to do...like so:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"String with a link" attributes:nil];
NSRange linkRange = NSMakeRange(14, 4); // for the word "link" in the string above
```

All well and good, however, how do you elegantly deal with language. This particular app switches from English to Georgian and, of course, the character position will change, too.

I have thought of detecting the locale of the phone and altering the NSMakeRange accordingly but wanted to know if there was a more established way to do this?

Comment: You have the swift tag.  And you show two lines of code in Objective-C.  Isn't that odd?

Comment: why not `NSRange linkRange = [@"String with a link" rangeOfString:@"link"];`，replace the corresponding string with the multi-language string `NSLocalizedString`

Comment: I have gathered many excellent answers on this topic and created a small blob on GithHub It's very simple to integrate and use. I don't want to go into too much details since it's all been already explained thoroughly in above answers. My solution is based on those answers. This class will detect URLs in any text, highlight them and make them tappable. Tapped URL will be opened in the external browser. You can easily add localization to this, as long as URLs stay the same and remain URLs. Just localize passed string to whichever language you want. [HyperlinkedUILabel](https://github.com/Yoorqu